# Turn off the return message from the executed command

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal

I'm developing a bash script, I've used `ssh` command in my bash script to run some commands on a remote server and I need to get the result from the command which runs on the remote server. so I wrote this code:

```
db="$(ssh -t user@host 'mysql --user=username -ppassword -e \"SHOW DATABASES;\" | grep -Ev \"(Database|information_schema|performance_schema)\"' | grep -Ev \"(mysql)\")"
```

But each time which I run my bash script, I will get `Connection to host closed.` in first of the `db` result. this is a default message from `ssh` command.

Also, If I use `> /dev/null 2>&1` end of my command the `db` variable would be empty.

How can I turn off the return message from the executed command?

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

db=$(
    ssh -t user@host bash<<EOF
    mysql --user=username -ppassword -e "SHOW DATABASES" |
    grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema|performance_schema|mysql)" \
    2> >(grep -v 'Connection to host closed')
EOF
)
```

or if `Connection to host closed` comes from `STDOUT` :

```
...
mysql --user=username -ppassword -e "SHOW DATABASES" |
grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema|performance_schema|mysql|Connection to host closed)"
...
```